# How to set a specific RewriteRule?

Tags: apache, http

I´m setting up a new RewriteRule and the Webpage will not be shown. It throws a HTTP-Error like 404 or BadRequest. This depends on the combination which i use.
Is the rewrite which i want to use in general possible?

We want to configure following Rewrite:

This Rewrite works:

```
RewriteRule ^/context1/contetx2/context3/context4/Reisen.de.html  https://www.test.at/context1/contetx5/context6/2018/context7/Reisen.html  [R=301,L]
```

But we want to "remove" the Path/Location "2018" in the URL which is shown in the browser. 
It should looks like:
 https://www.test.at/context1/contetx5/context6/context7/Reisen.html

I treid already a lot of combinations with R, QA, P, L, PT;
ProxyPass, RewriteCond and so on.

Expected:
enter the URL:
https://www.test.at/context1/contetx2/context3/context4/Reisen.de.html

shown in Browser (adress-line):
https://www.test.at/context1/contetx5/context6/context7/Reisen.html

Content is reachable with:
https://www.test.at/context1/contetx5/context6/2018/context7/Reisen.html

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^/context1/contetx2/context3/context4/Reisen.de.html  /context1/contetx5/context6/context7/Reisen.html  [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/context1/contetx5/context6/context7/Reisen.html  /context1/contetx5/context6/2018/context7/Reisen.html  [L]
```

Comment: Hello,thanks a lot. It works now but we changed the second entry from [L] to [P,L].

Comment: `[P]` should not be needed unless original and rewritten path are not on the same server